# How do I get the contents of a 1-line text file into the bash command buffer?

Tags: command-line

My purpose is to quickly retrieve saved bash commands and edit the commands in the bash command buffer (e.g. changing arguments, to experiment with long complex commands).
When I press Enter, the command will execute, and pressing Arrow Up, will get me the command again for further editing.

For example, I have a text file called `textfile`, with the following contents:
`ls -l`
I want to get that file content into the command buffer so that I get
`user@ubuntu:~$ ls -l`
Because now I can modify and re-execute it.

If I add the execute bit to `textfile`, I can execute it, but pressing Arrow Up, sets the `./textfile` command into the command buffer, not the contents.

Similarly if I enter `$(<textfile)` it also executes the command, but pressing Arrow Up, just gives me the `$(<textfile)` command, not its contents

The only solution I can think of is to do `cat textfile` and then copy / paste the contents into the terminal window. Well, I could also edit the file, save it, and execute it, but that's a hassle to do each time. So, is there a trick to get the contents of a file into the command buffer without typing or pasting?

Comment: Would the [`edit-and-execute-command`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#index-edit_002dand_002dexecute_002dcommand-_0028C_002dxC_002de_0029) readline command help? `C-xC-e` start `$VISUAL` which on my machine is `vim`, there `:r textfile` then `:x`. That will execute the command and from that moment will be available through the history too (unless some configuration explicitly forbids it).

Comment: That will help, thanks, although I had hoped for a slightly easier way, like a shortcut in bash itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command buffer you are referring to is the bash history file... a history of bash commands.  The history buffer is written to `~/.bash_history` when you log out of the terminal.  It's loaded into the buffer when you log in.

You can get the line you want into your bash history buffer by appending the line to your ~/.bash_history file, then manually reloading your bash history file into your buffer with the `history -r` command.

This is an example:

```
$ echo "command wanted" >> ~/.bash_history && history -r
```

Now when you hit the up arrow you will see "command wanted" in your "command buffer".

With this command line you will see the content of your `textfile` when you hit the up arrow:

```
$ echo $(<textfile) && cat textfile >> ~/.bash_history && history -r
```

Be sure to have your `textfile` terminated with a newline.